# What would be the correct definition of a functor F

Tags: category-theory, functors

I understand that functors map categories.
But I'm confused by the notation, which mostly comes from the fact that categories contain both objects and morphisms.

Normally when I say $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, I would expect it to have exactly one mapping, e.g. $f \colon x \mapsto 2x$, but for functors, I have two mappings:

$$
\begin{align}
& F \colon \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D} \\
& F \colon X \mapsto F(X) \\
& F \colon (f \colon X \to Y ) \mapsto (F(f) \colon F(X) \rightarrow F(Y))
\end{align}
$$

Is this correct? If I have to map over all elements of $\mathcal{C}$, should this also include the composition $\circ$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. A functor tells you how to map both objects and morphisms from one category to another.

Comment: Incidentally, for essentially this reason, the Coq library `MathClasses` uses the notation `fmap F` for the morphism mapping component of a functor `F`.

Comment: The action of $F$ on morphisms has to have certain properties. Namely $F(\text{id}_A) = \text{id}_{F(A)}$ and $F(f)\circ F(g) = F(f\circ g)$. When the latter is satisfied, $F$ is called covariant.

Comment: The reason that a functor contains two mappings instead of one is that a category has two underlying sets instead of one.

Answer (score 2):

yes, that's correct. And that's include the composition. if we have g:Z→X
F:(f∘g:Z→Y)↦(F(f∘g):F(Z)→F(Y))
and that's called covariant Functor, and one example of it, is homology functor.
furthermore, there's other type called contravariant functor 
as the following
F:C→D
F:X↦F(X)
F:(f:X→Y)↦(F(f):F(Y)→F(X)).